# Why may USR1 signals sent from background jobs in a Bash script not be reliably received by the parent shell process waiting for their completion?

Tags: bash, signals, wait, bash-trap

I have a Bash script running a bunch of background jobs in parallel.
Under certain conditions, before a background job completes, it sends
a USR1 signal to the spawning Bash process (say, to inform that
some process that was run as a part of the job had terminated with
a nonzero exit code).

In a simplified form, the script is equivalent to the one shown below.
Here, for simplicity, each background job always sends a USR1 signal
before completion, unconditionally (via the `signalparent()` function).

```bash
signalparent() { kill -USR1 $$; }
handlesignal() { echo 'USR1 signal caught' >&2; }
trap handlesignal USR1

for i in {1..10}; do
    {
        sleep 1
        echo "job $i finished" >&2
        signalparent
    } &
done
wait
```

When I run the above script (using Bash 3.2.57 on macOS 11.1, at least),
I observe some behavior that I cannot explain, which makes me think
that there is something in the interplay of Bash job management and
signal trapping that I overlook.

Specifically, I would like to acquire an explanation for the following
behaviors.

1. Almost always, when I run the script, I see fewer *“signal caught”*
   lines in the output (from the `handlesignal()` function) than there
   are jobs started in the `for`-loop—most of the time it is one to
   four of those lines that are printed for ten jobs being started.

   *Why is it that, by the time the `wait` call completes, there
   are still background jobs whose signaling `kill` commands had
   not been yet executed?*
2. At the same time, every so often, in some invocations of the script,
   I observe the `kill` command (from the `signalparent()` function)
   report an error regarding the originating process running the script
   (i.e., the one with the `$$` PID) no longer being present—see the
   output below.

   *How come there are jobs whose signaling `kill` commands are still
   running while the parent shell process had already terminated?
   It was my understanding that it is impossible for the parent
   process to terminate before all background jobs do, due to the
   `wait` call.*

   ```
   job 2 finished
   job 3 finished
   job 5 finished
   job 4 finished
   job 1 finished
   job 6 finished
   USR1 signal caught
   USR1 signal caught
   job 10 finished
   job 7 finished
   job 8 finished
   job 9 finished
   bash: line 3: kill: (19207) - No such process
   bash: line 3: kill: (19207) - No such process
   bash: line 3: kill: (19207) - No such process
   bash: line 3: kill: (19207) - No such process
   ```

Both of these behaviors signalize to me a presence of a race condition
of some kind, whose origins I do not quite understand. I would
appreciate if anyone could enlighten me on those, and perhaps even
suggest how the script could be changed to avoid such race conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html#Signals) as follows.

> When bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the `wait` builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the `wait` builtin to return immediately with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.

So, you need to repeat `wait` until it returns 0 to make sure all background jobs have terminated, e.g.:

```bash
until wait; do
    :
done
```

> It was my understanding that it is impossible for the parent process to terminate before all background jobs do, due to the `wait` call.

That is a misunderstanding; `wait` may return due to reception of a signal for which a trap has been set while there are running jobs at the background, and that may lead to normal completion of the program, with the side effect of leaving those jobs orphaned.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding *‘Almost always, when I run the script, I see fewer “signal caught” lines in the output’*—

According to [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> **Standard signals do not queue**. If multiple instances of a standard signal are generated while that signal is blocked, then only one instance of the signal is marked as pending (and the signal will be delivered just once when it is unblocked).

One way to change your script so that the signals do not arrive at the same time is as follows:

```bash
signalparent() {
    kill -USR1 $$
}

ncaught=0
handlesignal() {
    (( ++ncaught ))
    echo "USR1 signal caught (#=$ncaught)" >&2
}
trap handlesignal USR1

for i in {1..10}; do
    {
        sleep $i
        signalparent
    } &
done

nwaited=0
while (( nwaited < 10 )); do
    wait && (( ++nwaited ))
done
```

Here is the output of the modified script with Bash 5.1 on macOS 10.15:

```
USR1 signal caught (#=1)
USR1 signal caught (#=2)
USR1 signal caught (#=3)
USR1 signal caught (#=4)
USR1 signal caught (#=5)
USR1 signal caught (#=6)
USR1 signal caught (#=7)
USR1 signal caught (#=8)
USR1 signal caught (#=9)
USR1 signal caught (#=10)
```

Comment: Aha, that explains behavior 1, then! Thank you. Combined with @oguz’s answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65489164/254635), it answers my question completely. (I now have an impossible task of deciding which of the answers to accept, though, as each covers one of the two parts of the question.)

Comment: As an aside irrelevant to the original script: Perhaps the `for`-loop with the repeated invocations of `sleep` could be replaced with a simple `sleep ".$i"` in this case?

Comment: we all wish bash could do floating-point calculation.

Comment: Oh, right. I guess, `sleep "$(echo ".1*$i" | bc -l)"` is the only correct way out of this annoyance in general, then.

Comment: personally i hate bc which is a bit heavy-weight. :)

Comment: Yeah, but I’m not sure that the alternatives avoiding external calculators like `bc`, e.g., in the form of `scale=3; printf '%.*f' "$scale" "$((10**scale * i/10))e-$scale"`, are that much better than `bc -l <<<".1*$i"`, at the end of the day. :–)

Comment: Works great as long as we do not need to change that 0.1 multiplier later; otherwise, it does not scale well, as you, I’m sure, fully realize. Anyway, whatever works is fine.

Comment: for demo only purpose i can simply `sleep $i`. just dont want others to wait too long to try the script. :)